# Change the export stl file code from Exported from Blender-x.x.x to object name

Tags: export, add-on, stl

I want export model into stl format in ASCII, which Blender can do. However when I open the exported stl file by text, the first line is always like this:

> solid Exported from Blender-2.91.2

And the last line is:

> endsolid Exported from Blender-2.91.2

I want to change the string "Exported from Blender-2.91.2" to my stl file name, so I have to open my stl files again and again to change the name. This bothers me a lot and I don't know how to fixed it once and for all. I tried to open the addon folder io_mesh_stl(path:2.91\scripts\addons) and find in file stl_utils,line 75:

> return "Exported from Blender-" + bpy.app.version_string

Is it because this line? How can I fix my problem? Thanks a lot if anyone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Slippery Slope.**

Would investigate doing this in a post pro way, Using something like [`sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files)   or python, to run thru stl files and automate the bothersome edit, rather than updating the addon code.

That said, a quick edit to change the header when writing to ASCII

`stl_utils.py`

```
def _ascii_write(filepath, faces):
    from mathutils.geometry import normal

    with open(filepath, 'w') as data:
        fw = data.write
        header = _header_version()
        fw('solid %s\n' % header)

        for face in faces:
            # calculate face normal
            fw('facet normal %f %f %f\nouter loop\n' % normal(*face)[:])
            for vert in face:
                fw('vertex %f %f %f\n' % vert[:])
            fw('endloop\nendfacet\n')

        fw('endsolid %s\n' % header)
```

change the code (circa line 205) from

```
header = _header_version()
```

to

```
header = filepath
```

or to hack it just to use the filepath stem `"/path/foo/bar/stem.extension"`

```
from pathlib import Path
header = Path(filepath).stem
```

or to hack it just to use the filname (with extension) `"/path/foo/bar/filename"`

```
from pathlib import Path
header = Path(filepath).name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution seems working. Now it changes to my file path. However I want  to change it to my file name rather than my file path. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Seems? Added code to add just the stem of a filepath `"/path/foo/bar/stem.extension"`

Comment: I already tried your way. What I mean is that now the stl file change to:  solid C:\Users\-\Desktop\filename.stl   but I want it to be:   solid filename    (just the file name)

Comment: Thanks! I used the third way. Now it's working perfectly. The exist of extension doesn't bother me.